# Android Wear Development - Notification

Tags: android

Main Questiion is Trigger Notification;

3.3 Trigger Notification:
• Implement a mechanism for triggering notifications for tasks that are due within the next one hour.
• The Wearable device notification should include the Task ID, Task Name.
• The notification should also include an action which will load a new screen.
• This new screen should show all the tasks that are due within the next one hour.

1. Needs Solution how i get notification before one hour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.